# jQuery Appear Function for Image

Tags: jquery, html, function

Hello I have a jQuery to open picture only in browser visible area:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('det_img_^').appear(function() {
    var a = $(this).find('a');
    $(this).html('<img src="' + a.attr('href') + '" title="' + a.text() + '" />');
  });
});
```

HTML code should be:

```
<img class=" " id="det_img_54837261"
src="http://site.com/image54837261.jpg" 
alt="" title="" border="0" height="190">
```

Code doesn't work, need to fix jQuery part to work with this HTML code. I tried an original example http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/wiki/Examples it worked fine for me. JS files all included.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you included that js files which contains appear..? because appear is not a traditional jquery function

Comment: this code worked for you or not. explain clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with `#` for ID selector ?

`$('#det_img_^').appear(function() {`

or

`$('img#det_img_^').appear(function() {`

Comment: I added the code but mine is not being displayed when I scroll to the DIV. I get an error `elements[i].appear` is not a function